# How to prove this property of condition expectation?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation

I'm trying to prove the following property of conditional expectation
$$E[f(X)Y+g(X)|X]=f(X)E(Y|X)+g(X)$$
I know that 
$$E[f(X)Y+g(X)|X]=E[f(X)Y|X]+g(X)$$
But I can't see why 
$$E[f(X)Y|X]=f(X)E(Y|X)$$ 
What am I missing out? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: fiy I edited in above the missing conditionals  $E[f(X)Y|X]$ in $E[f(X)Y]$. I'm assuming their absence was a typo - ok?

Comment: @peterag Thanks. It wasn't really a typo though. In fact, I was thinking of $X$ as conditioning only the second term in $E[f(X)Y+g(X)]$. Just knowing that the two terms are being conditioned on it makes it all much clearer already, lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $X=x$, $f(X)$ is equal to $f(x)$ and can be treated as a constant while evaluating the conditional expectation:

$$E[f(X)Y|X=x]=E[f(x)Y|X=x]=f(x)E[Y|X=x]$$

or in terms of random variables

$$E[f(X)Y|X]=f(X)E[Y|X]$$